# 1064: SQL syntax error executing PyMySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am using PyMySQL to execute SQL query commands from python. My pystyle is `pyformat` which was found using:

```
>>> pymysql.paramstyle
pyformat
```

My db and cursor details are as follows:

```
>>> MYDB = pymysql.connect(_params_)
>>> cursor = MYDB.cursor()
```

I then execute a SQL query using,

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %(tablename)s",  {"tablename": "activity"})
```

I get an error stating,

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
 right syntax to use near '''activity''' at line 1")
```

On the other hand, the query by itself works,

```
>>> unsafe_sql = ("Select * from activity")
>>> cursor.execute(unsafe_sql)
>>> 4
```

I am not sure what is going on with my first query. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should have backticks around `%(tablename)s`, not single quotes.

Comment: sorry, was trying something there......even without single quotes it does not work....will update the query

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? because the error message shows the quotes.

Comment: I think the problem may be that `cursor.execute()` automatically wraps any substituted values with quotes. You'll need to do normal string formatting for the table name. Only use `cursor.execute()` substitution for values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a table name as a parameter to `cursor.execute()`. Whenever a parameter is a string it quotes it when it substitutes into the query. Use a normal string formatting method, e.g.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %(tablename)s" % {"tablename": "activity"})
```

Comment: Ugh, these are the kind of things that drive me nuts when learning. If only the error message could be just a bit more specific :/ Googling this error was also tough (at least for me). I ran into the same issue with `LOAD DATA` and the  `INTO TABLE <table_name>` part where at least to me it seems a bit more natural to make the table a variable .... Thanks!